# Jsoup can't find video in webpage

Tags: android, parsing, video, jsoup

I want get vide tag after get src . But when i parsing with jsoup, its can't find it.
Webpage placing where mix.tj/video/113989.html

from this code i pars site

```
class Loading extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    Document document = null;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("http://mix.tj/video/113989.html").get();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(document != null)
        {
            Log.e("hello",document.getElementsByTag("link").attr("href"));
            Log.e("hello",document.getElementsByTag("video").attr("src"));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
```

Site have only 1 tag video

I found problem. In html code have script which created this video

```
<script>var player = jwplayer('player-embed');      
player.setup({"file": "http://dushanbe.mix.tj/video/2/45/5bafae1306081.mp4", "image": "/img/b/7/42/113989.jpg", "aspectratio": "16:9", "autostart": false, "controls": true, "displaydescription": false, "displaytitle": false, "flashplayer": "/player/jwplayer-7.8.7/jwplayer.flash.swf", "key": "n+94L7vjfQNGEin57ap3glk3iRNum2o7AeOIWw==", "mute": false, "ph": 1, "pid": "mS6Np6yN", "preload": "auto", "primary": "html5",  "repeat": false, "stagevideo": false, "stretching": "uniform", "width": "100%"});</script>
```

And i have new question. Who it do ?

Comment: Can you show the line from where you want to extract video url

Comment: i found the problem. In html placed this script